# Update file name within Google Drive API through JQuery in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

In my Ruby on Rails application, I am using Google Drive API to manage folders and files stored in Google Drive.

What I want is to update a file/folder name in the same view (in place) through jQuery, so the user doesn't need be redirected to another view just for it.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass the Google Id of the file/folder to the controller because the url parameter with that information 
doesn't show up in the form tag.

Here is my code:

View:

```
<% @folders.each do |f| %>
<%= image_tag("#{f.icon_link}") %> <%= link_to f.name, folders_path + '?gid=' + f.id, id: 'ftext' %>  - <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_subf_path + '?gid=' + f.id, id: 'edit_link', remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function()  {
$('#edit_link').click(function() {
$("#ftext").append('<%= j render('form_subf') %>');
});
});
```

_form_subf.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag edit_subf_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, params[:gid] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Atualizar' %>
<% end %>
```

Form output:

```
<form action="/clients/subf" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
  <input name="id" id="id" type="hidden">
  <input name="commit" value="Atualizar" data-disable-with="Atualizar" type="submit">
</form>
```

clients_controller:

```
def edit_subf
client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
client.update!(session[:authorization])
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.authorization = client
service.update_file(params[:id], params[:name], fields: 'id, name') 
redirect_to root_path
end
```

Rootes:

```
get 'clients/subf' => 'clients#edit_subf'
```

I have already tried variations of params in the view and _form pages but without success. Also, I tried the gem Best in Place but seems it only works with models, and my files are stored directly in Google Drive.